# Easy Extraction of features from a Feature dataset ( Not feature class)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, export, select-by-attribute

My Feature dataset (residing inside a GDB) contains more than 30 feature classes and every month I like to extract features from this GDB based on one attribute, which is repeating in all the feature classes. For example `Job_Month = "May"`.

Is there any tool available in ArcGIS which will extract all the features in a Geodatabase (or Feature dataset) at one time using an SQL statement? The extract data wizard does not have any filter/SQL for attributes.

Expected simple solutions, but seems not an easy one.

Comment: I think it only requires a couple of dozen lines of Python code wrapped around the Select tool and ListFeatureClasses to do this.

Comment: @ PolyGeo - The valid feature types for ListFeatureClass are mostly Geometry based..Will the code able to isolate features based on attribute, anyway thanks  Annotation —
Arc —.
Dimension —
Edge —
Junction —
Line —.
Multipatch —
Node —
Point —
Polygon —
Polyline —
Region —
Route —
Tic —

Comment: You would use the Select tool to "isolate features based on attribute". Your use of terms like Tic, etc suggests that you may be used to using coverages and it sounds like you are wanting to archive data in a geodatabase so have you considered [**Geodatabase Archiving**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000sr000000)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you have a GeoDatabase with 30 FeatureClasses which may be of different geometry types but they all share a common field "Job_Month" which you want to use to select and extract data out by?

A very simple model would achieve this which you can build in model builder. You would have a FeatureClass Iterator feeding into a Select tool where you can set the expression. Have a look at this [page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Examples_of_using_iterators_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001n000000/).